# Background image not covering on tablet

Tags: html, css, background-image

When I visit my site on my tablet the Background stops displaying after the footer? It doesn't behave like this on my desktop when i reduce the window size however.

This is the site: http://www3.carleton.ca/clubs/sissa/html5/video.html

CSS:

```
body{
    width: 100%; /*always specify this when using flexBox*/ 
    height:100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-box-pack:center; /*way of centering the website*/
    -moz-box-pack:center;
    box-pack:center;
    background:black;
    background:url('images/bg/bg14.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
    -moz-background-size: cover !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

This is what it looks like on my nexus 7:
[image]

When I use a different user agent in the browser it covers the entire background:
[image]

HTML:

```
<!--Site Main Body--> 
<div id="wrapper">
    <section id="body_div">

    </section>

    <footer id="footer">
        &copy; Copyright  by SimKessy
    </footer>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will help and I haven't got the possibility to test it, but you could try adding the background properties to the `html` element instead of the `body` element.

I removed `!important`, but you can add that back if you need it.

```
html {
    background:black;
    background:url('images/bg/bg14.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
body {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```